# How to store only n records in database sequelize?

Tags: node.js, architecture, sequelize.js

I'm building a chat app.

I am storing messages in DB. But I don't want to store infinite chats messages, only last, lets say, 100 messages.

How can I limit so only 100 messages are stored and if new ones show up delete old ones?

Do i run a query per chat message?

Should I add background tasks in background, that runs sql query for every user?

Does database have something built in?

Do i add some sort of indexes?

How is it done in production?

Answer (score 1):

Best option with **sequelize** , is to use **[HOOKS](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html)** ,     **`afterCreate(instance, options)`**

```
const Chat = sequelize.define('chat', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    ... // Other fields
}, {
  hooks: {
    afterCreate: (chat, options) => {
        // check the total records and perform your operation based on that
        // if its greater than 100 then remove it
    }
  }
});
```

> Make sure you are using `Chat.create();` or sequlize method to insert
>   data , and not raw query or else hooks will not work

---

Another good option is to set **[cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)** , on hourly or daily basis that can check the total messages on respective time and then perform the action.